# Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting a merge between two data frames.  Each data frame has two index levels (date, cusip).  In the columns, some columns match between the two (currency, adj date) for example.

What is the best way to merge these by index, but to not take two copies of currency and adj date.

Each data frame is 90 columns, so I am trying to avoid writing everything out by hand.

```
df:                 currency  adj_date   data_col1 ...
date        cusip
2012-01-01  XSDP      USD      2012-01-03   0.45
...

df2:                currency  adj_date   data_col2 ...
date        cusip
2012-01-01  XSDP      USD      2012-01-03   0.45
...
```

If I do:

```
dfNew = merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

I get

```
dfNew:              currency_x  adj_date_x   data_col2 ... currency_y adj_date_y
date        cusip
2012-01-01  XSDP      USD      2012-01-03   0.45             USD         2012-01-03
```

Thank you!
    ...

Answer (score 232, accepted):

You can work out the columns that are only in one DataFrame and use this to select a subset of columns in the merge.

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns.difference(df.columns)
```

Then perform the merge (note this is an index object but it has a handy `tolist()` method).

```
dfNew = merge(df, df2[cols_to_use], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

This will avoid any columns clashing in the merge.

Comment: What if the key is a column and it's called the same? It would be dropped with the first step.

Comment: Due to the constrain in the above comment, I went with the answer of @rprog below

Comment: If the key is a column, to use this answer, convert the columns to use to a list (`cols_to_use = cols_to_use.tolist()`) and append name of your key column to this list (`cols_to_use.append('key_column_name')`). You also need to change the merge from using `left_index` and `right_index` to using `on='key_column_name'`.

Answer (score 190):

I use the `suffixes` option in [`.merge()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) followed by `drop()`:

```
dfNew = df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,
                 how='outer', suffixes=('', '_y'))

dfNew.drop(dfNew.filter(regex='_y$').columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Thanks @ijoseph

Comment: Would be a more helpful answer if it included the code for `filter`ing (which is fairly straightforward, yet still time-consuming to look up/ error-prone to remember). i.e.     `dfNew.drop(list(dfNew.filter(regex='_y$')), axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: I find this solution better because I can still merge using one of the columns as a reference instead of the index. Then, I can only remove the duplicates. Thank you!

Comment: Best solution. You may consider including elaborate regex as suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569496/3755989)

Comment: I'm going to be that person flagging a case when an original column name ends in `_y` so that it would be dropped as well:)

Answer (score 25):

Building on @rprog's answer, you can combine the various pieces of the suffix & filter step into one line using a negative regex:

```
dfNew = df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,
             how='outer', suffixes=('', '_DROP')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_DROP)')
```

Or using `df.join`:

```
dfNew = df.join(df2, lsuffix="DROP").filter(regex="^(?!.*DROP)")
```

The regex here is keeping anything that **does not** end with the word "DROP", so just make sure to use a suffix that doesn't appear among the columns already.

Answer (score 7):

I'm freshly new with Pandas but I wanted to achieve the same thing, automatically avoiding column names with _x or _y and removing duplicate data. I finally did it by using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034085/1101553) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314641/1101553) from Stackoverflow

sales.csv

```
    city;state;units
    Mendocino;CA;1
    Denver;CO;4
    Austin;TX;2
```

revenue.csv

```
    branch_id;city;revenue;state_id
    10;Austin;100;TX
    20;Austin;83;TX
    30;Austin;4;TX
    47;Austin;200;TX
    20;Denver;83;CO
    30;Springfield;4;I
```

merge.py
import pandas

```
def drop_y(df):
    # list comprehension of the cols that end with '_y'
    to_drop = [x for x in df if x.endswith('_y')]
    df.drop(to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)


sales = pandas.read_csv('data/sales.csv', delimiter=';')
revenue = pandas.read_csv('data/revenue.csv', delimiter=';')

result = pandas.merge(sales, revenue,  how='inner', left_on=['state'], right_on=['state_id'], suffixes=('', '_y'))
drop_y(result)
result.to_csv('results/output.csv', index=True, index_label='id', sep=';')
```

When executing the merge command I replace the `_x` suffix with an empty string and them I can remove columns ending with `_y`

output.csv

```
    id;city;state;units;branch_id;revenue;state_id
    0;Denver;CO;4;20;83;CO
    1;Austin;TX;2;10;100;TX
    2;Austin;TX;2;20;83;TX
    3;Austin;TX;2;30;4;TX
    4;Austin;TX;2;47;200;TX
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of going around the problem, but I have written a function that basically deals with the extra columns:

```
def merge_fix_cols(df_company,df_product,uniqueID):
    
    df_merged = pd.merge(df_company,
                         df_product,
                         how='left',left_on=uniqueID,right_on=uniqueID)    
    for col in df_merged:
        if col.endswith('_x'):
            df_merged.rename(columns = lambda col:col.rstrip('_x'),inplace=True)
        elif col.endswith('_y'):
            to_drop = [col for col in df_merged if col.endswith('_y')]
            df_merged.drop(to_drop,axis=1,inplace=True)
        else:
            pass
    return df_merged
```

Seems to work well with my merges!

Answer (score 3):

If the indexes are the same (big if true!) you can do:

```py
df = df1.copy()
df[df2.columns] = df2
```

this similar to `merge`

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, index_left=True, index_right=True)
```

but with no duplicate columns

Comment: As per 2023, this should be the accepted answer, because it is concise and expressive.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the duplicate `y` columns you don't want after the join:

```
# Join df and df2
dfNew = merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

Output: `currency_x | adj_date_x | data_col1 | ... | currency_y | adj_date_y | data_col2`

```
# Remove the y columns by selecting the columns you want to keep
dfNew = dfNew.loc[:, ("currency_x", "adj_date_x", "data_col1", "data_col2")]
```

Output: `currency_x | adj_date_x | data_col1 | data_col2`

Answer (score 0):

can't you just subset the columns in either df first?

```
[i for i in df.columns if i not in df2.columns]
```

```
dfNew = merge(df **[i for i in df.columns if i not in df2.columns]**, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

When the amount of columns you want to avoid is lower than the columns you want to keep... you could use this kind of filtering:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['currency', 'adj_date'])]
```

This will filter  all columns in the dataframe except the 'currency' and 'adj_date' columns, you have to write the merge something like this:

```
    dfNew = merge(df, 
                  df2.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['currency', 'adj_date'])], 
                  left_index=True,
                  right_index=True,
                  how='outer')
```

Note the "~", it means "not".

Answer (score 0):

You can include duplicate columns in the key to merge on to ensure only a single copy appears in the result.

```py
# Generate some dummy data.
shared = pd.DataFrame({'key': range(5), 'name': list('abcde')})
a = shared.copy()
a['value_a'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 5)
b = shared.copy()
b['value_b'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 5)

# Standard merge.
merged = pd.merge(a, b, on='key')
print(merged.columns)  # Index(['key', 'name_x', 'value_a', 'name_y', 'value_b'], dtype='object')

# Merge with both keys.
merged = pd.merge(a, b, on=['key', 'name'])
print(merged.columns)  # Index(['key', 'name', 'value_a', 'value_b'], dtype='object')
```

This method also ensures that values in columns that appear in both data frames are consistent (e.g. that the currency in both columns is the same). If they are not, the corresponding row will be dropped (if `how = 'inner'`) or occur with missing values (if `how = 'outer'`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're merging on arbitrary columns and don't want to keep the *right key* this will do the trick:

```py
mrg = pd.merge(a, b, how="left", left_on="A_KEY", right_on="B_KEY")
mrg.drop(columns=b.columns.difference(cols_to_use))
```