# Pandas performance issue of dataframe column "rename" and "drop"

Tags: performance, pandas

Below is the line_profiler record of a function :

```
Wrote profile results to FM_CORE.py.lprof
Timer unit: 2.79365e-07 s

File: F:\FM_CORE.py
Function: _rpt_join at line 1068
Total time: 1.87766 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
  1068                                           @profile
  1069                                           def _rpt_join(dfa, dfb, join_type='inner'):
  1070                                               ''' join two dataframe together by ('STK_ID','RPT_Date') multilevel index.
  1071                                                   'join_type' can be 'inner' or 'outer'
  1072                                               '''
  1073                                           
  1074         2           56     28.0      0.0      try:    # ('STK_ID','RPT_Date') are normal column
  1075         2      2936668 1468334.0     43.7          rst = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, how=join_type, on=['STK_ID','RPT_Date'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
  1076                                               except: # ('STK_ID','RPT_Date') are index
  1077                                                   rst = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, how=join_type, left_index=True, right_index=True)
  1078                                                   
  1079                                           
  1080         2           81     40.5      0.0      try: # handle 'STK_Name
  1081         2       426472 213236.0      6.3          name_combine = pd.concat([dfa.STK_Name, dfb.STK_Name])
  1082                                                   
  1083                                                   
  1084         2       900584 450292.0     13.4          nameseries = name_combine[-Series(name_combine.index.values, name_combine.index).duplicated()]
  1085                                                   
  1086         2      1138140 569070.0     16.9          rst.STK_Name_x = nameseries
  1087         2       596768 298384.0      8.9          rst = rst.rename(columns={'STK_Name_x': 'STK_Name'})
  1088         2       722293 361146.5     10.7          rst = rst.drop(['STK_Name_y'], axis=1)
  1089                                               except:
  1090                                                   pass
  1091                                           
  1092         2           94     47.0      0.0      return rst
```

What surprise me is these two lines:

```
  1087         2       596768 298384.0      8.9          rst = rst.rename(columns={'STK_Name_x': 'STK_Name'})
  1088         2       722293 361146.5     10.7          rst = rst.drop(['STK_Name_y'], axis=1)
```

Why a simple dataframe column `"rename"` and `"drop"` operation costs that much percentage of time (8.9% + 10.7%)?  Anyway, the `"merge"` operation only costs 43.7% , and "rename"/"drop" looks not like a calculation-intensive operation.  How to improve it ?

Comment: `rename` takes an `inplace` arg, so you can instead do `rst.rename(columns={'STK_Name_x': 'STK_Name'},inplace=True)` not sure what difference this would make but I would expect it would be an improvement, my thoughts on this would be that it is having to copy the dataframe and that this is probably the cause of the cost but this is just a guess

Comment: can you post a dataset with code?

Comment: also pls post version of pandas

Comment: Almost the same scenario with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns/19125531#19125531 , and i try to optimize as more as i can. pandas version is 0.11 and i will post the dataset later on when i back to office .