# Merge two csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I trying to merge two csv file, I don't want to remove duplicate I want simply to check first column "PDB ID" and then check second column "Chain ID". all values has input files. I want to merge and add column file 1 and file 2.

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("testfile_1.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='PDB ID')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

I used above script but getting result one row three time same value.

```
File 1: Input
PDB ID  Chain ID    Ligand ID   Uniprot Acc
3RSQ    A   NAI   Q9X024
3RTD    A   NAI   Q9X024
1E3E    A   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3E    B   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    A   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    B   NAI   Q9QYY9

File 2: Input
PDB ID  Chain ID    Avg
1E3E    A   31.566
1E3E    B   17.867
3RSQ    A   57.653   
1E3I    A   27.63
1E3I    B   17.867
3RTD    A   48.806

Getting Output: 
PDB ID  Chain ID_x  Avg Ligand ID   Uniprot Acc
3RSQ    A   57.653  NAI   Q9X024
3RTD    A   48.806  NAI   Q9X024
1E3E    A   31.566  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3E    A   31.566  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3E    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3E    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    A   27.63   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    A   27.63   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9


Expected Output:

3RSQ    A   57.653  NAI   Q9X024
3RTD    A   48.806  NAI   Q9X024
1E3E    A   31.566  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3E    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    A   27.63   NAI   Q9QYY9
1E3I    B   17.867  NAI   Q9QYY9
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `left_index` and `right_index` parameters of [pandas `merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method to not duplicate rows. Additionally, using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125531/6779606) to not duplicate column names, I suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("testfile_1.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
cols = b.columns.difference(a.columns)
merged = a.merge(b[cols], left_index=True, right_index=True)
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

which resulted in this:

```
   Chain ID Ligand ID PDB ID Uniprot Acc     Avg
0        A       NAI   3RSQ      Q9X024  57.653
1        A       NAI   3RTD      Q9X024  48.806
2        A       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  31.566
3        B       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  17.867
4        A       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9   21.63
5        B       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9  17.867
```

---

## EDIT:

In order to accomplish this when the indices of each DataFrame do not correspond to the same `PDB ID`, I ended up sorting DataFrame `a` to retrieve its indices and setting the indices of the sorted version of DataFrame `b` to these values. Finally, I sort DataFrame `b` by its indices and `PDB ID` should be ordered the same way as DataFrame `a`.

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("testfile_1.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
b = b.sort_values(by='PDB ID')
b.index = a.sort_values(by='PDB ID').index
b = b.sort_index()
cols = b.columns.difference(a.columns)
merged = a.merge(b[cols], left_index=True, right_index=True)
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

where merged resulted in this:

```
    Chain ID Ligand ID PDB ID Uniprot Acc     Avg
0        A       NAI   3RSQ      Q9X024  57.653
1        A       NAI   3RTD      Q9X024  48.806
2        A       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  31.566
3        B       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  17.867
4        A       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9   27.63
5        B       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9  17.867
```

---

## EDIT 2:

Here is a much simpler solution, as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27314641/6779606).

```
import pandas as pd


a = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("testfile_1.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on=['PDB ID', 'Chain ID'], how='outer')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

The number of rows do not have to be equal and the result should be what you expect (my last row is an example of different number of rows):

```
  Chain ID Ligand ID PDB ID Uniprot Acc     Avg
0        A       NAI   3RSQ      Q9X024  57.653
1        A       NAI   3RTD      Q9X024  48.806
2        A       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  31.566
3        B       NAI   1E3E      Q9QYY9  17.867
4        A       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9   27.63
5        B       NAI   1E3I      Q9QYY9  17.867
6        a         a      a           a     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually file1 column A "PDB ID" and File2 column "PBD ID" is not same sequence. I have edited above input file. I tried above code but getting same input file as output because both file column A "PDB ID" is not same sequence.

Comment: I edited my answer where it should work for these unsorted "PDB ID" sequences. It assumes both DataFrames have the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks but getting  Error: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3049 elements, new values have 3060 elements

Comment: I believe that is referring to where I set the index on DataFrame `b`, meaning DataFrame `a` has 21 more rows than DataFrame `b` so my assumption of having the same number of rows was incorrect. I found a simpler solution so I'm updating my post with that now.