# How to merge multiple csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have several csv files that has same first row element in it.
For example:

```
csv-1.csv:
Value,0
Currency,0
datetime,0
Receiver,0
Beneficiary,0
Flag,0
idx,0

csv-2.csv:
Value,0
Currency,1
datetime,0
Receiver,0
Beneficiary,0
Flag,0
idx,0
```

And with these files (more than 2 files by the way) I want to merge them and create something like that:

| left | csv-1 | csv-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Value | 0 | 0 |
| Currency | 0 | 1 |
| datetime | 0 | 0 |

How can I create this funtion in python?

Comment: Isn't it better to have first column as header and second column from each file as rows? Anyway, what have you tried so far - show your code ([mre])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two pandas dataframes results in "duplicate" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313647/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-results-in-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

out = (pd.concat([pd.read_csv(csvfile, header=None, index_col=[0], names=[csvfile.stem])
           for csvfile in sorted(pathlib.Path.cwd().glob('*.csv'))], axis=1)
         .rename_axis('left').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          left  csv-1  csv-2
0        Value      0      0
1     Currency      0      1
2     datetime      0      0
3     Receiver      0      0
4  Beneficiary      0      0
5         Flag      0      0
6          idx      0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you must create indexes in dataframes by first columns, on which you will further join:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('csv-1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv-2.csv')

df1 = df1.set_index('col1')
df2 = df2.set_index('col1')

df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

Then rename the column names if needed, or make a new index

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

def refineFilename(path):
    return path.split(".")[0]

df=pd.DataFrame()

for file in glob("csv-*.csv"):
    new=pd.read_csv(file,header=None,index_col=[0])
    df[refineFinename(file)]=new[1]

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={0:"left"},inplace=True)

print(df)

"""
          left  csv-1  csv-2
0        Value      0      0
1     Currency      0      1
2     datetime      0      0
3     Receiver      0      0
4  Beneficiary      0      0
5         Flag      0      0
6          idx      0      0
"""
```

What we are doing here is making the `df` variable store all data, and then iterating through all files and adding a second column of those files to `df` with file name as the column name.

Comment: Looking like just the longer version of [@Corralien's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438549/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files#75438818) :P