# Pandas merge two dataframes without duplicating column

Tags: python, pandas

My question is similar to [Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns) but I cannot find a solution for the specific example below.

I have DateFrame df:

```
Customer    Address
J. Smith    10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu
```

and Dataframe emails:

```
Name        Email
J. Smith    j.smith@myemail.com
```

I want to merge the two dataframes to produce:

```
Customer    Address                 Email
J. Smith    10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu    j.smith@myemail.com
```

I am using the following code:

```
data_names = {'Name':data_col[1], ...}
mapped_name = data_names['Name']
df = df.merge(emails, how='inner', left_on='Customer', right_on=mapped_name)
```

The result is:

```
Customer    Address                 Email                 Name
J. Smith    10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu    j.smith@myemail.com   J. Smith
```

While I could just delete the column named mapped_name, there is the possibility that the mapped_name could be 'Customer' and in that case I dont want to remove both Customer columns.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can even drop unwanted column using df.drop(mapped_name, axis=1, inplace=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can rename first column in `email` dataframe to `Customer`, `how='inner'` can be omit because default value:

```
emails.columns = ['Customer'] + emails.columns[1:].tolist()

df = df.merge(emails, on='Customer')
print (df)
   Customer               Address                Email
0  J. Smith  10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu  j.smith@myemail.com
```

And similar solution as another answer - is possible rename first column selected by `[0]`:

```
df = df.merge(emails.rename(columns={emails.columns[0]:'Customer'}), on='Customer')
print (df)
   Customer               Address                Email
0  J. Smith  10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu  j.smith@myemail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just rename your email name column to 'Customer' and then merge. This way, you don't need to worry about dropping the column at all.

```
df.merge(emails.rename(columns={mapped_name:'Customer'}), how='inner', on='Customer')
Out[53]: 
   Customer               Address                Email
0  J. Smith  10 Sunny Rd Timbuktu  j.smith@myemail.com
```