# Merge avoiding duplicate columns but keeping only one duplicate

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I have two dataframes that I want to merge, but I want to avoid to have duplicate columns, so I'm doing:

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns-df1.columns
```

If I print cols_to_use I get this:

```
 Index([col1,col2,col3...],dtype=object)
```

However, I have one column that I need it to be kept in both dfs, it is the co_code. That's because I'm going to merge on that column.

My question is: how to add one extra column to cols_to_use? I need it to look like this:

```
Index([co_code,col1,col2,col3...],dtype=object)
```

I tried different synthaxes but nothing seemed to work:

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns-df1.columns+'co_code'
cols_to_use = df2.columns-df1.columns+['co_code']
cols_to_use = df2.columns-df1.columns+df2['co_code'].columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns - df1.columns.difference(['co_code'])
```

Or,

```
cols_to_use = (df2.columns - df1.columns).tolist() + ['co_code']
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @COLDSPEED's solution:

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns.difference(df1.columns.drop('co_code'))
```