# Add a value to pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes which i want to merge without duplicating columns:

First i'm getting only unique columns from second dataframe( As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19125531/9751444) answer):

```
cols_to_use = df2.columns.difference(df1)
```

I need to keep one column which is the unique identifier for me, with the name `complete_name`

Right now, `cols_to_use` does not contain `complete_name` because it was marked as duplicate, how can i add it? I've tried:

```
cols_to_use.append(pd.Index(['complete_name']))
```

But it does nothing. Any help?

Comment: Do you think `cols_to_use.union(['complete_name'])` ?

Comment: still doesnt work @jezrael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it working nice:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

cols_to_use = df1.columns.difference(['A','C'])
print (cols_to_use)
Index(['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], dtype='object')

print (cols_to_use.append(pd.Index(['complete_name'])))
Index(['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'complete_name'], dtype='object')

print (cols_to_use.union(['complete_name']))
Index(['B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'complete_name'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: U'r right, i used just `cols_to_use.append(...)` instead of `cols_to_use = cols_to_use.append(...)` ... time consuming mistake

Comment: @MikeVlad - I am not surprised, because pure python `append` working `inplace` (not assign necessary), but in pandas is used [`Index.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.append.html). It looks similar, but different functions.