# Concatenate distinct columns in two dataframes using pandas (and append similar columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

My question is closely related to [Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns) **but not identical.**

I want to concatenate the columns that are different in three dataframes. The dataframes have a column id, and some columns that are identical: Ex.

df1

```
id place name qty unit A 
1 NY    Tom   2  10   a
2 TK    Ron   3  15   a
3 Lon   Don   5  90   a
4 Hk    Sam   4  49   a
```

df2

```
id place name qty unit B 
1 NY    Tom   2  10   b
2 TK    Ron   3  15   b
3 Lon   Don   5  90   b
4 Hk    Sam   4  49   b
```

df3

```
id place name qty unit C D
1 NY    Tom   2  10   c d
2 TK    Ron   3  15   c d
3 Lon   Don   5  90   c d
4 Hk    Sam   4  49   c d
```

Result:

```
id place name qty unit A B C D
1 NY    Tom   2  10   a b c d
2 TK    Ron   3  15   a b c d
3 Lon   Don   5  90   a b c d
4 Hk    Sam   4  49   a b c d
```

The columns place, name, qty, and unit will always be part of the three dataframes, the names of columns that are different could vary (A,B,C,D in my example). The three dataframes have the same number of rows.

I have tried:

```
cols_to_use = df1.columns - df2.columns
dfNew = merge(df, df2[cols_to_use], left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

The problem is that I get more rows than expected and columns renamed in the resulting dataframe (when using concat).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `reduce` from `functools`

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right), [df1,df2,df3])
Out[725]: 
   id place name  qty  unit  A  B  C  D
0   1    NY  Tom    2    10  a  b  c  d
1   2    TK  Ron    3    15  a  b  c  d
2   3   Lon  Don    5    90  a  b  c  d
3   4    Hk  Sam    4    49  a  b  c  d
```

Comment: Excellent, time to go back to documentation :)

Comment: Great! Do you think this solution will be the most efficient? I have a large dataset.

Comment: @mig what is the real size ?

Comment: @wen about 20000 rows (streams)

Comment: @mig all the function should work then , 20000 rows is not consider big , I usually work with 10 million row , and both merge and concat work for me .

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested merge

```
merge_on = ['id','place','name','qty','unit']
df1.merge(df2, on = merge_on).merge(df3, on = merge_on)



    id  place   name    qty unit    A   B   C   D
0   1   NY      Tom     2   10      a   b   c   d
1   2   TK      Ron     3   15      a   b   c   d
2   3   Lon     Don     5   90      a   b   c   d
3   4   Hk      Sam     4   49      a   b   c   d
```

Comment: Maybe check with `df= reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right'), dfs)`

Comment: Aha ok , posted

Comment: Thanks! I will try it

Answer (score 2):

Using `concat` with `groupby` and `first`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], 1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

```
   A  B  C  D  id name place  qty  unit
0  a  b  c  d   1  Tom    NY    2    10
1  a  b  c  d   2  Ron    TK    3    15
2  a  b  c  d   3  Don   Lon    5    90
3  a  b  c  d   4  Sam    Hk    4    49
```

Comment: Please explain what the different parameters and functions do?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract only those columns from `df2` (and `df3` similarly) which are not already present in `df1`. Then just use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the data frames:

```
cols = [c for c in df2.columns if c not in df1.columns]
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[cols]], axis=1)
```