# How to iteratively merge data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, frames

Given a list of data frames, I want to iteratively merge them and return single dataframe. Inputs: `frames` (list of pandas data frames) and `on_columns` (string or list of strings containing the column names to merge). How do I use `df.merge` to accomplish this?
    """
    Given a list of data frames, iteratively merge them and return a 
    single dataframe

```
"""HINT: Use slice on frames when iterating and merging.

Arguments:
    frames {list} -- a list of pandas DataFrames
    on_columns {string or list} -- a string or list of strings
     containing the column names on which to join

Returns:
    df -- a pandas.DataFrame containing a merged version of the 
    two provided dataframes. If frames is None or an empty list return None
"""
def merge(frames, on_columns):
     #implementation here
     df = #merged df



return df
```

Edit: I think maybe I can use df.concat but am not sure how?

Comment: Are the on columns the same in each case? Seems like a case for `reduce` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614977/concatenate-distinct-columns-in-two-dataframes-using-pandas-and-append-similar/52615147#52615147)

Comment: It is similar but I want to merge all the columns that are provided in `on_columns` not just ones that are different from each other.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: I edited it - hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work,

```
def merge(frames, on_columns):
    #implementation here
    if not frames:
        return None
    if len(frames) == 1:
        return frames[0]
    out = frames[0]
    for df in frames[1:]:
        out = out.merge(df, on=on_columns)
    return out
```

Comment: Cool, can you accept this as the answer then by upvoting?

Comment: you can remove the second if statement

Comment: @DoganAskan I did, but since I am not above 15 reputation yet, my upvote isn't publicly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = next(dfs)
for records in dfs:
    df = df.append(records)

# the above is equivalent to
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

caveats:

- `dfs` is an iterator of pandas.DataFrame objects
- each of the `dfs` has the same columns
- might want to reindex after all the appends are done
- tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce but it's not obvious what the function(df1, df2) should be (i.e. `pd.concat` expects an iterable); anyway the `pd.concat` utility does the reduce
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_functions.html lists the `pd.concat` and other utilities

  - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge
  - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat

P.S. don't create a function that the library provides already, be happy to read the docs and re-read the docs, esp. since the pandas docs are volumes