# Merge two dataframe in pandas and combining column_x with column_y after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

First data frame:(Name has only first name)

```
df_Math
Date        RollNo  Name    Math_Score
2019-01-01  1       A       45
2019-01-01  2       B       60
2019-02-01  1       A       70
```

Second data frame:(Name has first and last name)

```
df_Science
Date        RollNo  Name    Science_Score
2019-01-01  1       A A     50
2019-01-01  3       C C     80
2019-02-01  2       B B     90
```

**Required data frame:**

```
Date        RollNo  Name    Science_Score   Math_Score
2019-01-01      1   A       50              45
2019-01-01      2   B       NaN             60
2019-01-01      3   C C     80              NaN
2019-02-01      1   A       NaN             70
2019-02-01      2   B B     90              NaN
```

Merge statement: `df_Math.merge(df_Science, on=['Date', 'RollNo'], how='outer')` gives the result but it contain Name_x and Name_y. I want only one Name column it should take from df_Math, if it's NaN it should take from df_Science like in required dataframe.

Can anyone please help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `suffixes` to `merge` first and then use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `Name_`:

```
df = df_Math.merge(df_Science, on=['Date', 'RollNo'], how='outer', suffixes=('','_'))
df['Name'] = df['Name'].fillna(df.pop('Name_'))
print (df)
         Date  RollNo Name  Math_Score  Science_Score
0  2019-01-01       1    A        45.0           50.0
1  2019-01-01       2    B        60.0            NaN
2  2019-02-01       1    A        70.0            NaN
3  2019-01-01       3  C C         NaN           80.0
4  2019-02-01       2  B B         NaN           90.0
```

Comment: 2nd line did the trick .. fillna with pop combination I was unaware about .. thanks for posting ur answer

Answer (score 0):

You should check this thread -

[Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns)

use the suffixes in merge -

```
df_Math.merge(df_Science, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer', suffixes=('','_y'))
```