# How to merge Dataframe smartly as the pictures show

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fetching data from web, and I want to merge them together by Key1 and Key2. The idealy case is that, we got df1 - df6 in a sequence (picture 1).

But most common case, we cannot estimate which part of data we can get next (picture 2).

[image: pic 1 and pic 2]

In the second case, I want to put the new data to the correct place according to the Key1 and Key1 and its column name. If column or row not exists, a new column or row should be added for it. And missing data fills with NaN.

I've tried merge, join and concat, but I can't archieve the final targe. Now my implemention is: merge df1 - df3 and df4 - df6, the concat the result together. But it's not "smart" enough, and sometime error will occours if the data not in this sequence.

Main code:

```
    result_daily = pro.daily(ts_code=ts_code, start_date=ts_since, end_date=ts_until)
    result_adjust = pro.adj_factor(ts_code=ts_code, start_date=ts_since, end_date=ts_until)
    result_index = pro.daily_basic(ts_code=ts_code, start_date=ts_since, end_date=ts_until)

    print(uri + ' - Network finished, time spending: ' + str(clock.elapsed_ms()) + 'ms')

    sub_result = None
    sub_result = merge_on_columns(sub_result, result_daily, ['ts_code', 'trade_date'])
    sub_result = merge_on_columns(sub_result, result_adjust, ['ts_code', 'trade_date'])
    sub_result = merge_on_columns(sub_result, result_index, ['ts_code', 'trade_date'])

    result = pd.concat([result, sub_result], ignore_index=True)
```

Also the merge_on_columns():

```
def merge_on_columns(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame, columns: str or [str]):
    if df1 is None:
        return df2
    if df2 is None:
        return df1
    if not isinstance(columns, (list, tuple)):
        columns = [columns]
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns/19125531#19125531
    diff_cols = list(df2.columns.difference(df1.columns))
    # if len(diff_cols) == 0:
    #     df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=columns, sort=False)
    # else:
    merge_columns = diff_cols + columns
    df = pd.merge(df1, df2[merge_columns], how='inner', on=columns, sort=False)
    return df
```

Could someone help me. Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you mentioned, you're getting? Could you also share data, which accompany that error? (Like what exactly are you merging, when error occurs)

Comment: Not the exception error, but the data doesn't merge as expect. Because I just merge df1 - df3, df4 - df6, then concat their result together, if df4 comes following df1, the merge operation will not work as expect).