# Merging several dataframes into one without creating duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes:

```
array = {'name': ['Trevor', 'John', 'Trevor', 'John', 'Trevor', 'Trevor', 'John'], 'day': ['2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00', '2020-10-11 08:00:00'
        , '2020-10-11 12:34:00', '2020-10-11 09:12:00'], 'number': [5,0,3,5,1,8,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
array1 = {'name': ['Trevor'], 'color': ['red']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1)
array2 = {'name': ['John'], 'color': ['blue']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2)
df
```

I want to merge df1 & df2 into df in the real world I have hundreds of df1, df2, df3...), so the output would be:

```
    name    day              number color
0   Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00 5   red
1   John    2020-10-11 08:00:00 0   blue
2   Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00 3   red
3   John    2020-10-11 08:00:00 5   blue
4   Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00 1   red
5   Trevor  2020-10-11 12:34:00 8   red
6   John    2020-10-11 09:12:00 6   blue
```

Comment: Have you looked through this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns

Comment: Yes. This is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `merge` and `concat`:

```
df.merge(pd.concat([df1,df2]), on='name', how='left')
```

Output:

```
     name                  day  number color
0  Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00       5   red
1    John  2020-10-11 08:00:00       0  blue
2  Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00       3   red
3    John  2020-10-11 08:00:00       5  blue
4  Trevor  2020-10-11 08:00:00       1   red
5  Trevor  2020-10-11 12:34:00       8   red
6    John  2020-10-11 09:12:00       6  blue
```

---

**Update**: Try `loc` update every time you get a new `df#`:

```
df.loc[df['name'].isin(df1['name']), 'color'] = df1['color'].iloc[0]

df.loc[df['name'].isin(df2['name']), 'color'] = df2['color'].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, BUT I have hundreds of df# - not just two

Comment: How do you store that hundreds of `df#`? you can easily pass the list `pd.concat(list_of_dfs_)`?

Comment: Problem is I get them one at a time and need to "merge" them one at a time to df

Comment: @gtomer you should mention that in your question. See updated answer if it helps.

Comment: `current_df = current_df.merge(pd.concat([current_df, new_df]), ....`

Comment: @Quang - thank you for your help. It is mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.merge(df,df1.append(df2), how='left', on='name')
```

Comment: Thanks, BUT I have hundreds of df# - not just two

Comment: Parse them as a list. Concat become more useful then