# How to I join two pandas DataFrames that have the same multiple columns? I don't want duplicates such as Date.a | Date.b

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames of Date | Region | District. I want to combine these two dataframes so there is not Date.a | Date.b | Region.a | District.a Region.b | District.b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Merge columns must be present in both dataframes

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, on=["Date", "Region", "Disctric"])
```

Comment: That creates a dataframe with only the merge columns, but no rows

Comment: Delivery_Data = d_6_2_21.append(d_2_22_20, ignore_index=True) worked perfectly for me. The index was messing it up.