# left join creating column_x and column_y

Tags: pandas, merge

HJello guys,

I wanzt to do a left join like below, but im gotting date1_x, date1_y and date2_x and date2_y. What i want is to replace the column if it exists.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

df1

id, date1, val1,  date2
1,  '2021-03-10', 'XEP', '2021-04-10'

df2

```
 id,    date1,      date2
 1,  '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04'
 2,  '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'
 3,  '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08'
```

Resulting df:

```
1,  '2021-09-03', 'XEP' , '2021-09-04'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns)

Comment: Sample data and expected output is necessary for avoid not helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but merging as followed should work if date1 and date2 are equal in both dataframes.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=['id', date1, date2], how='left')
```

Comment: no . i want to do left join . df1 and df2 both contains columns date1 and date2. I want to do leeft join with replacing values of date1 and date2 of my df1 dataframe. Thank you in advance. @kylian

Comment: Can't you just simply delete the date1 and date2 column in df1 and join the date1 and date2 columns from df2 then?