# Why would a key double after a merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-merge

I merge two datasets using following code:

```
output1 = classen_gravity.merge(fdi, how= "left", right_on=["Country", "Year", "regime"],
                               left_on=["country", "regime", "year"])
```

"regime" is supposed to stay as one column but after a merge, it becomes regime_x and regime_y.

Why would it happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merge - How to avoid duplicating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125091/pandas-merge-how-to-avoid-duplicating-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the order of the columns is the same:

```py
output1 = classen_gravity.merge(
   fdi,
   how= "left",
   right_on=["Country", "Year", "regime"],
   left_on=["country", "year", "regime"] # this was ["country", "regime", "year"]
)
```

To avoid problems with the column naming, it's best to impose uniform naming:

```py
fdi.columns = fdi.columns.str.lower()
output2 = classen_gravity.merge(
   fdi,
   how= "left",
   on=["country", "year", "regime"],
)
```